# Scrolling between two specific pixel point

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".right").click(function () {
            $("p").animate({right: "-=64px"});
    });
$(".left").click(function(){
        $("p").animate({right: "+=64"});
    });
```

How i can make two specific pixels point, that my icons just moving between those.

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/000227/n759P/1/)

I want my icons navigate in table and anytime they arrive to the end of gray color, stop and dont move anymore. just can move inverse on the other button.

is it possible with .css("right") ?
If yes, please guide me how.

Thanks.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n759P/3/

Comment: No. If it arrives to the end of that gray line, dont move in that side anymore, In this case,when i click double in any button, the icon will go outside of that gray line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VQwtp/3/

**js**

```
var movementFactor = 30;

var minWidth = $('#animSubject').width();
var maxWidth = $('#animArea').width();

$("#right").click(function () {
    var subWidth = $('#animSubject').width();
    if (maxWidth > (subWidth + movementFactor)) {
        $("#animSubject").animate({
            width: "+=" + movementFactor + "px"
        });
    } else if (maxWidth > subWidth) {
        $("#animSubject").animate({
            width:(maxWidth) + "px"
        });
    }

});
$("#left").click(function () {
    var subWidth = $('#animSubject').width();
    if (minWidth < (subWidth - movementFactor)) {
        $("#animSubject").animate({
            width: "-=" + movementFactor + "px"
        });
    } else if (minWidth < subWidth) {
        $("#animSubject").animate({
            width:(minWidth) + "px"
        });
    }
});
```

You can vary `movementFactor` to move images with required distance with one click.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new fiddle for you,

The point is if you want something to move between 2 points, you shouldn't use "-=64px" or "+=64px".

Just use a static point.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/599eB/1/)

So that means you should use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".right").click(function () {
        $("p").animate({right: "0"});
});
$(".left").click(function(){
    $("p").animate({right: "320px"});
});
```

Comment: but its a little different.

Comment: But i want to move for example 64px with any click, till arrive to the end of the gray line. anytime it arrives to the end line, dont move in that side any more.

Comment: Still searching for this solution? Just add in a little if statement, saying: if( $(p).css("right") != "320px") { move animation } (This is from the top of my head, I haven't tested it

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/y51aI2/preview) here, you can check

Comment: Thanks i see. But its working with one icon, if i add 3 more icon, it wont work. 
I want it to move for example 50px with any click, till arrive to the end of the gray line.

Comment: you can calculate rightend i.e. offset().left+ width(). Then just apply logic for calculation if(img.offset.left < rightend)  //dont move further } else { //move 50px } @Mehran

Comment: let me check please. Thanks for help